# plot multiple layers: geom_raster() with geom_point()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following part of my all data:

```
structure(list(Datetime = structure(c(1604188800, 1604192400, 
1604196000, 1604199600, 1604203200, 1604206800, 1604210400, 1604214000, 
1604217600, 1604221200, 1604224800, 1604228400, 1604232000, 1604235600, 
1604239200, 1604242800, 1604246400, 1604250000, 1604253600, 1604257200, 
1604260800, 1604264400, 1604268000, 1604271600, 1604275200, 1604278800, 
1604282400, 1604286000, 1604289600, 1604293200), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), amb_var = c(NA, NA, NA, 1.0014694795, 0.983929716666667, 
0.955620169666667, 0.989994305166667, 0.949170644666667, 1.02736884383333, 
1.0634456996, 0.757796259, 0.964273832833333, 1.0010119495, 0.8585854745, 
1.011050308, 1.13641933433333, 1.111877249, 1.09221488333333, 
1.07883340533333, 1.109587318, 1.0872007085, 1.0272168345, 1.10487714875, 
1.04610194266667, 1.02695567333333, 1.051095495, NA, 1.09990141116667, 
1.00926073433333, 1.00053694283333), date_ = structure(c(1604188800, 
1604188800, 1604188800, 1604188800, 1604188800, 1604188800, 1604188800, 
1604188800, 1604188800, 1604188800, 1604188800, 1604188800, 1604188800, 
1604188800, 1604188800, 1604188800, 1604188800, 1604188800, 1604188800, 
1604188800, 1604188800, 1604188800, 1604188800, 1604188800, 1604275200, 
1604275200, 1604275200, 1604275200, 1604275200, 1604275200), tzone = "", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), time_ = structure(c(0, 3600, 7200, 10800, 14400, 
18000, 21600, 25200, 28800, 32400, 36000, 39600, 43200, 46800, 
50400, 54000, 57600, 61200, 64800, 68400, 72000, 75600, 79200, 
82800, 0, 3600, 7200, 10800, 14400, 18000), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), bio_var = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 10, 
5, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, 1, 1, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, 5, 1, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 2, 2, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_)), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I trying plot this data as a geom_raster() of abiotic variable and a geom_point() of my biotic variable over the geom_raster().

I don't know where are the error of my script.

my ggplot code are:

```
lims2 <- as.Date(c("2020-11-01","2022-06-10"))
ggplot() + 
  geom_raster(data = df, aes(x = date_, y = time_, fill = amb_var), interpolate = T) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = c("lightblue","yellow", "red")) + 
  geom_point(data = df, aes(x = time_, y = date_, size = bio_var)) +
  scale_y_datetime(date_breaks = "3 hours", date_labels = "%H:%M") +
  scale_x_datetime(date_labels = "%m-%Y", breaks = "2 months", 
                   limits = as.POSIXct(lims2)) +
  labs(y = "HORA", x = "DATA", fill = "Variable") +
  theme_test() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 20, angle = 45,
                                   vjust = 1, hjust = 1,
                                   color = "black", face = "bold"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 20,
                                   color = "black", face = "bold"), 
        axis.title.x = element_text(size = 20,
                                    color = "black", face = "bold"), 
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 20,
                                    color = "black", face = "bold"),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 20, face = "bold"),
        legend.title = element_text(size = 20, face = "bold"),
        plot.title = element_text(size = 20, face = "bold"))
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: You don't explain what the problem is. I see your x/y are swapped between the two geoms, that's probably not right for the `geom_point()` layer.

Comment: Thanks. I see this problem now. I change x/y in geom_point(). Thanks!